# My External Hard Drive is not Working

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive

So I have had my external hard drive for a while but recently it had been not working. It will not show up on my Desktop, Finder, or Disk Utility. I have been to Best Buy and they said it could be a formatting problem but I can't reformat it because it won't show up.

please watch this video provided: [My hard drive is not working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7esETTZVlhk)

If you know how to fix this, please help! This hard drive costed me almost $100 and I don't want to have to replace it.

**Edit:**
My mac supports USB 3.0

Comment: Try a different port or different computer. If it still fails it's more then likely its dead. It might be under warranty you could try to call the manufacturer for a repair.

Comment: Tony: It appears that you have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.

Comment: I'd try the 3rd party app Mountain.  See if you drive shows up when you run it. if so, see if you can mount it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out what is wrong with it. Most drives like that have LED lights to indicate if they are getting power. If the lights aren't turning on, I would recommend getting a new connecting cable for your drive, assuming you have tested the USB port beforehand. You should, in theory, be able to get the lights to turn on, at least briefly by plugging the drive into a USB charger. 
If the lights do turn on, but you cannot retrieve the data, then you need to plug the drive into a computer with a different os and try to reformat it in there. Unlikely, but possible to work.

Answer (score 0):

@matterny The light on my drive is not turning on but you can hear it spinning. When I took it to Bestbuy they tried a different cord and that did not work either. When I plugged it into a usb charger, it did light up but it pulsed fast.

Comment: Is your computer USB port outputting enough power? By that I mean it has to be super speed (ss) or a  blue USB port. If you are using one of these, the next step would be to run disk utility and see if it's in there. If the issue is anything like you expect, Mac would be a hard operating system to try to fix it on, at least for me

Comment: That's the spec that I mentioned before, only some recent USB standards support enough power for some drives. If the USB port is black with no other markings, its not enough.

Comment: How do I know if it is giving enough power?

Comment: So, checking the specifications of the USB port compared to the external drive is the best way to do it, basically a little research if he ports aren't labeled.

Comment: The inside of the port, like the female end on my computer?

Comment: The inside of the port is what should be blue, if there is enough power. Idk what kind of ports your computer has, but the cable for the drive there's a blue part and that should connect to a blue part if it's going to work.

Comment: yeah I see the blue part on my drive's usb my computers Is white if that helps.

Comment: Wait I found it, my computer is usb 3.0

Comment: So, 3.0 does meet the minimum specifications for most external drives, assuming that you've tried all the USB ports on your computer, no real solutions without using windows, and those are low success chance options

Comment: I have other windows computers in my house, how would I fix the drive on them?

Comment: The first thing I think of would be trying disk management (right click windows icon), or device manager on windows. I wonder if it's an os thing that a different computer could read. I had a USB drive become unreadable on Windows before and only appear for Ubuntu os. However, it's not real likely. Probably worth trying though

Comment: Tony: It appears that you have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles”.